# How to get data in PHP from AJAX jQuery request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I've followed all your advice about making an jQuery or Javascript AJAX request to a php file on a server.

The problem I'm running in to is that my response is this

> **Fatal error**:  Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in

So here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".ex .select").click(function(){
    $("body").data("id", $(this).parent().next().text());
```

Those lines serve to capture a variable and save it as data on the body element, so I can use it later.

But I want to send that same variable to PHP file, to add to a complex API request - eventually to return the results, create $_SESSION variables and so forth

```
    var pageId = {
        id: $("body").data("id"),
    };
```

But let's avoid that as a problem and just make my array simple like

```
var pageId = {
        id: "12345",
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: pageId,
        datatype: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        }
    });
});
});
```

And for now at least I was hoping to keep my PHP file simple for testing my grasp of the concepts here

```
<?php

$id = $_GET('id');

echo json_encode($id);

?>
```

I'm expecting the response

> Data: 12345
>
> Status: Success

But I get the Error Message above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `$_GET('id')` to `$_GET['id']`
and in order to send status, you need to add status to an array just like below and try to parse JSON on your response.

```
<?php

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = array("id"=>$id, "Status"=>"Success");

    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

And access in jquery using `.` like if you use data variable in success then

```
success:function(data){
    alert(data.Status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `$id = $_GET('id');` to `$id = $_GET['id'];`

**because $_GET, not a function it's an array type element.**

Comment: And since its encoding to json and the ajax datatype is json, would he also need to use jQuery.parseJSON() on data?